# Can I receive messages that was sent to my telegram bot, when it's was offline (not polling)?

Tags: python-3.x, api, bots, telegram, message

**Example:**

1. I turn my bot off.
2. Users sent their messages.
3. I get my bot online again (bot.polling()). And I want to receive messages that was sent.

Is there way to get them?

Comment: "Incoming updates are stored on the server until the bot receives them either way, but they will not be kept longer than 24 hours" https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update So simply calling getUpdates() should work

Comment: @Martheen, thank you! Your answer is really helpful.